# How do I split a variable length field using html

Tags: javascript, html, field, separator

How do I insert a space/carriage return after a designated number of characters (eight) within a designated html field pulling from a table?

Example:

```
<ebs:PMLOAD TABLE='DS_CLAIM'><ebs:PMVAL FIELD='DS_CLAIM.CGROUPING_FIELD'></ebs:PMVAL></ebs:PMLOAD>
```

So if the field contains 12345678910, the output would read:

```
12345678
910
```

Comment: You will need JavaScript to do this.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML you don't.
JavaScript is the handler, Using replace method.

```
str = "1234567890";
alert(str.replace(/^(.{8})(.*)$/mg,'\1 \2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = string.split(""), output;
arr.splice(8, 0, ' ');
output = arr.join('');
```